# How to make overlay with flutter at least on Android?

Tags: flutter, dart, overlay

Here is the image of a working app:

[image]
[image]

The icon is persistent. When I navigate to other apps, it should not disappear. A Custom text also can be displayed and updated. Thank you in advance. This question is asked many times, but without a clear answer. Should I write a native plugin for it and call within flutter?

How this is implemented? And Can it be implemented with flutter?

Comment: You cannot implement it with only Flutter. On the other hand, you might find a package which is supposed to do so.